# C++ DOUBLE* return and then reset

Tags: c++, windows

I have the following function:

private:

```
bool _bFixation;
bool _bBlink;
DOUBLE _X;
DOUBLE _Y;


int CMYCLASS::getData(VARIANT_BOOL* uEvent1, VARIANT_BOOL* uEvent2, DOUBLE* uX, DOUBLE* uY, LONG* pVal)
{
    if (_bEvent1)
    {
        *uEvent1=VARIANT_TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        *uEvent1=VARIANT_FALSE;
    }
    if (_bEvent2)
    {
        *uEvent2=VARIANT_TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        *uEvent2=VARIANT_FALSE;
    }

    uX=&_X;
    uY=&_Y;

    //reset

    _bEvent1=false;
    _bEvent2=false;
    _X=0;
    _Y=0;

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that if I reset the variable _X at the end of the function, it also changes the variable uX.

Can somebody tell me how to do that correctly? Do I have to make a copy of _X instead of passing the reference?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean "Do I have to make a copy of uX instead of passing the reference"

Comment: Why are you all-capsing `DOUBLE`? Do you seriously have a macro for that? What does it expand to?

Comment: @user2357112 What do you mean, please?

Comment: You should specify your toolchain environment to avoid downvotes ...

Comment: The standard type is `double`. I don't know what `DOUBLE` is supposed to be. Where does the definition come from? What is the definition?

Comment: `uX` is a pointer , in this ` uX=&_X;` row u making it to point to `_X`. so if u change 1 of them the second will change too

Comment: @user2357112 He's probably using the Windows API.

Comment: @user2357112 One of his types is `VARIANT_BOOL` which is used in windows programming, which includes types such as `DOUBLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have been given a pointer as a parameter, and you are setting the location that pointer points to to the address of another variable that you then reassign.

Try something like:

`*uX = _X;`

This will copy the value of `_X` into the memory pointed to by `uX`.

You can then reassign `_X` to be whatever you want and it won't change the value pointed to by `uX`.